# Why is the minimum distance between two conics along their common normal?

Tags: calculus

Throughout my highschool mathematics for coordinate and as well as 3-D geometry.<s>Many</s> All formulae regarding the minimum distance between two curves are derived using the fact that the minimum distance is along their common normal.

Intuitively it's very obvious you draw a parabola, a circle whatever. The shortest distance is *always* along the common normal but algebraically or using calculus what would be a more *mathematical proof*?

Comment: The first order variation is $2\mathbf{x}_{A\to B}\cdot\mathrm{d}\mathbf{x}_{A\to B}$.

Answer (score 1):

This is about two curves $s\mapsto{\bf f}(s)$ and $t\mapsto{\bf g}(t)$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$ and *necessary conditions* for a local minimum (or maximum) of the distance between two (non-colliding) points on these two curves. The objective function is 
$$\Phi(s,t):=|{\bf f}(s)-{\bf g}(t)|^2=\bigl( {\bf f}(s)-{\bf g}(t)\bigr)\cdot\bigl({\bf f}(s)-{\bf g}(t)\bigr)\ .$$
Assume that for the parameter values $s_0$ and $t_0$ we have ${\bf d}:={\bf f}(s_0)-{\bf g}(t_0)\ne{\bf 0}$, and that $\Phi$ assumes a local minimum at $(s_0,t_0)$. Then
$$\Phi_s(s_0,t_0)=2{\bf f}'(s_0)\cdot({\bf f}(s_0)-{\bf g}(t_0)\bigr)=0\quad \wedge\quad\Phi_t(s_0,t_0)=-2{\bf g}'(t_0)\cdot\bigl({\bf f}(s_0)-{\bf g}(t_0)\bigr)=0\ .$$
But this is saying that ${\bf d}\perp{\bf f}'(s_0)$ and at the same time ${\bf d}\perp{\bf g}'(t_0)$.